# What exactly this method do ? addActionListener

Tags: swing, user-interface

What exactly will this addActionListener Do.....we we call button.addActionListener(this) what will happen

Comment: May be helpful: [ActionListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). This method adds an action listener to the component on which it is called. The argument passed in this is the name of listener that will listen for an action and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It basically adds `this` (the current object) to a list of objects that will be notified when the component has an action performed on it, such as a button being pressed.

It's a way of registering your interest in what is happening to the component and is useful in that you don't have to keep polling a component to check its status.

Your object (or class, really) simply implements the interface methods for listening (such as `actionPerformed`) and that method will be called for each event that happens.

The [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html) have a large variety of different articles on the various listeners that you're likely to use.